# iOS stopwatch label

Tags: ios, string, nsstring, stopwatch

I am pretty new to Objective C and therefore have a question for you guys.
I am making an Ice Skating app. I have a stopwatch label that works: 00:00.00 (mm:ss.SS).
Now I have 2 labels to display the laptime to the skater.
So I want one label to display the second small s from the left.
In another label I want to show the first big S from the left.
So in someway I have to use a specific part of the 0:00.00 label.

Assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(trackTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}



-(void)trackTime{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"s:S"];

    self.lbl.text=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Using formatter you can design any kind of string using date, like

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"Oh its s:S"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"My time is mm:ss:SS"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"Now mm"];
```

Hope it help.

Cheers.

Comment: As an aside, @user2969939, note that if this isn't the root view controller, make sure to `invalidate` the timer in `viewDidDisappear`, or else the timer will continue to execute, keeping a strong reference to the view controller, and you'll end up leaking the view controller.